# There is any difference between callback function and calling a function inside another function?

Tags: javascript, function, callback

Let's take this example:

```
function foo(callback){
        callback();
        baz();
  }

  function baz() {
        console.log('Hello from baz');  
   }

   foo(baz);
```

It looks like they are doing the same task. Or callback and calling a function inside another function are the same thing?

Comment: It's the same thing if the passed callback is the same

Comment: In which situation have we to choose a callback or call it straight inside a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except you aren't using the callback the way callbacks are supposed to be used. Callbacks are supposed to get the interim results from a previous function. Here's an example

```
function add (a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

function subtract (a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

This is the callback

```
function doLater (val) {
  if (val > 0) {
    console.log("positive");
  } else if (val ==) {
    console.log("zero");
  } else console.log ("negative");
}

function doOp (a, b, mathOp, callback) {
  var res = mathOp(a,b);
  callback(res);
}

doOp (2,3, add, doLater);
```

vs.

```
doOp (2,3,subtract, doLater);
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, they are doing the same, but callbacks are very useful because you can call the same function with many different callbacks. That makes your `foo` function more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, both approaches will do the same.

However, you can pass function as parameters, that are not in the functions scope.
E.g.

```
function foo(callbackFn){
    callbackFn();
    // function test is undefined here, since it was declared in another scope 
}

function bar(){
    // test is only available in bar's scope
    function test(){
        console.log("test");
    }
    foo(bar);
}
```